# How to get Android PreferenceFragment title/header to show in right pane?

Tags: android, preferences

I am creating a PreferenceActivity for a tablet app (Android 3.0+) using PreferenceFragments. The goal is to have a two-pane layout displaying the preferences just like the system preferences are displayed.

The issue I'm having is that I cannot for the life of me seem to get the title of the currently selected PreferenceFragment to display above the ListView of the PreferenceFragment in the right pane. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do (trying to display the content in red box.)

[image] 
Here is my preference_headers.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header android:fragment="com.mycompany.mobile.preferences.MyPreferencesActivityHC$GeneralSettingsPreferenceFragment"
            android:title="General Settings">
    </header>
    <header android:fragment="com.mycompany.mobile.preferences.MyPreferencesActivityHC$PhotoOptionsPreferenceFragment"
            android:title="Photo Settings"
            android:summary="Testing photo settings">
    </header>
</preference-headers>
```

and here is the code for MyPreferencesActivity.java

```
package com.mycompany.mobile.preferences;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

import com.mycompany.mobile.R;

public class MyPreferencesActivityHC extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle(R.string.taskCaptionSettings);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
    }

    public static class GeneralSettingsPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.general_settings_preferences);
        }
    }

    public static class PhotoOptionsPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.photo_options_preferences);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you showed here seems to be fine, but that is not everything. 
Look at [Device Admin example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) with the [code here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/DeviceAdminSample.html) I use the same technique in my app and it works great.

Comment: Thanks @Maxim. There was also a styling issue at play here. When I took it down to bare-bones, it started working.